# chemmacros reactions counter in report/book

Tags: counters, report, chemmacros

Is it somehow possible to add the chapter number to the `reaction` counter of `chemmacros` and to reset it if `chapter` increases? In `equation` and `figure` etc. the chapter is added before the counter, like 1.2 with first number the chapter and second number the figure etc. in `report`/`book` and KOMA `scrreprt`/`scrbook`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{modules=reactions}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Reactions without chapter number}
With x.y
\begin{equation}
f(x)=e^{\frac{1}{x}}
\end{equation}
Only with z
\begin{reaction}
    H2O + H3O+ -> H2O2 + H+
\end{reaction}
\chapter{And repeat booth with counter resetting}
With (x.1).y
\begin{equation}
    f(x)=e^{\frac{1}{x}}
\end{equation}
Only with z, but incremented.
\begin{reaction}
    H2O + H3O+ -> H2O2 + H+
\end{reaction}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `chemmacros` package has `\renewtagform` exactly for this (see page 35 of the package documentation). To be used for example as follows:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{modules=reactions}

\renewtagform{reaction}[\thechapter.]{(}{)}

% Phelype Oleinik's answer added: 
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{reaction}{chapter}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{Reactions without chapter number}
With x.y
\begin{equation}
f(x)=e^{\frac{1}{x}}
\end{equation}
Only with z
\begin{reaction}
    H2O + H3O+ -> H2O2 + H+
\end{reaction}
\chapter{And repeat booth with counter resetting}
With (x.1).y
\begin{equation}
    f(x)=e^{\frac{1}{x}}
\end{equation}
Only with z, but incremented.
\begin{reaction}
    H2O + H3O+ -> H2O2 + H+
\end{reaction}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As this solution does not need additional packages and is complete, I mark it as the correct one.

Answer (score 3):

With the `chngcntr` package:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{modules=reactions}

\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{reaction}{chapter}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Reactions chapter number}
With x.y
\begin{equation}
f(x)=e^{\frac{1}{x}}
\end{equation}
With x.z
\begin{reaction}
    H2O + H3O+ -> H2O2 + H+
\end{reaction}
\chapter{And repeat both with counter resetting}
With (x.1).y
\begin{equation}
    f(x)=e^{\frac{1}{x}}
\end{equation}
With x.z
\begin{reaction}
    H2O + H3O+ -> H2O2 + H+
\end{reaction}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

No additional packages or `\makeatletter` definitions necessary:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
% \usepackage{amsmath} already loaded by `chemmacros'
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{modules=reactions}
\numberwithin{reaction}{chapter}% provided by the `amsmath' package

\begin{document}

\chapter{Reactions without chapter number}
With x.y
\begin{equation}
f(x)=e^{\frac{1}{x}}
\end{equation}
Only with z
\begin{reaction}
    H2O + H3O+ -> H2O2 + H+
\end{reaction}
\chapter{And repeat booth with counter resetting}
With (x.1).y
\begin{equation}
    f(x)=e^{\frac{1}{x}}
\end{equation}
Only with z, but incremented.
\begin{reaction}
    H2O + H3O+ -> H2O2 + H+
\end{reaction}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is the command `\@addtoreset` which resets one counter when another is increased.

Just add this to your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{reaction}{chapter}
\makeatother
```

It will reset the `reaction` counter when the `chapter` counter is increased.